# Cannot send email verification link through development and production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sendgrid

sendgrid is not sending email verification link in development and production environment.
My environment.rb file looks like this

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
:password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
:domain => 'heroku.com',
:address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
:port => '578',
:authentication => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I added these two line in development.rb file look like this

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options ={:host => 'http://localhost:3000'}
```

In production.rb file I added these two lins

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options ={:host => 'warm-forest-79168.herokuapp.com', 
:protocol => 'https'}
```

In my .profile file I exported my sendgrid username and password

```
export SENDGRID_USERNAME=XXXXXXX
export SNDGRID_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXX
```

The rest to add confirmable in devise user I followed wiki https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

When I signup locally the mail is being sent but never recieved

```
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome deepakchauhan3294@gmail.com!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation? 
 confirmation_token=GKBtUsWUJ1N3HQow9d94">Confirm my account</a></p>
```

When I signup in production(heroku) I get the following error

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password
```

I have rechecked my username and password both are right still It is throwing error. Please help me I have been stuck in it for too long.

Comment: did you check your prod environment whether the values of ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'] and ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'] exists?

Have you verified the values in the terminal?

Comment: My ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'] is showing nil in terminal but when I use heroku config:get SENDGRID_PASSWORD then it is giving me the password. I guess ENV caused some problem. What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, you can just go to heroku console and export the env variables there. Here is a link for your help https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: I hope this is going to solve your problem :)

Comment: I have already set the env variables in heroku as config variables but still email can't be recieved.

Comment: are you monitoring logs? Did you see any error?

Comment: I did everything from scratch and this time added separate action mailer configuration in development and production with credentials stored in credentials.yml.enc. Now, everything is working. Glad because of you I got to know where the error was coming from thank you.

Comment: No problem mate, I'm glad that you finally figured it out!